# Скрипт не запускается из папки назначения, только из папки ниже по уровню

Tags: linux, bash

Имеется скрипт `tst.sh`, который лежит в папке `~/dest`. Не получается запустить этот скрипт из папки назначения, только уровнем ниже. Делаю следующее:

Перехожу в папку назначения:

```
cd dest
```

Создаю в ней простой скрипт `tst.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo The script works
```

Делаю его запускаемым:

```
chmod +x tst.sh
```

Пытаюсь запустить этот скрипт командой `tst.sh`. Скрипт не запускается, а появляется ошибка:

```
bash: tst.sh: command not found
```

Но если перейти на уровень ниже командой `cd ..` и запустить скрипт командой `dest/tst.sh`, то он выполнится и в терминале появится запись

`The script works`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что необходимо сделать, чтоб скрипт мог запускаться из папки назначения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы находитесь в папке, скрипт надо запускать вот так:

```bsh
./tst.sh
```

Comment: Благодарю, не знал этого!

Comment: Отметьте мой ответ решением

Comment: Через 7 минут, таковы условия stackoverflow